# ActionMailer cannot attach a HTML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am not sure why the email that I send via ActionMailer with an attachment doesn't show me the attachment instead the contents of the attachment is just shown / output into the email.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "email@email.com"

  def test_email()
    attachments['testresult1.html'] = {
      :filename => 'testresult1.html',
      :body => File.read('C:\\testresult1.html')
    }

  mail(:to => 'email@email.com',
    :subject => 'Cool great message'
  )
  end
end
```

The output of the email looks like this

```
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2012 14:11:52 +1000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8;
filename=testresult1.html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=testresult1.html
filename: testresult1.html
Content-ID: <4f8ced883c0d9_1b1c30b580813e@PC-049.mail>
```

and then the whole contents of the HTML file/attachment.

I'd expect the HTML file to be attached to the email as it would be attached to a normal email and I should be able to double click on the attachment and open it in a browser.

```
Email Client = Microsoft Outlook
Connection = SMTP
Rails = 3.2.1
ActionMailer = 3.2.1
Mail = 2.4.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try adding a `body` key to #mail.

Comment: Hi Thanks, that worked. Can you explain a bit as to why it worked..??

Comment: In my experience, an ActionMailer email which has an attachment and no body becomes a jumble of poorly crafted headers and content. I guess this should be chalked up to poor test coverage (their tests seem to assume there's always a body).

Comment: Ahh, I agree and makes perfect sense. Looks like a bug that has to be raised with the Ruby community. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot Philip :)

I was sending an attachment without any body attribute
I was facing following two problem:

1. name of PDF was always coming as "noname"
2. sometimes PDF was getting corrupted

But after adding body attribute to mail it works.

So, the correct syntax is:

```
attachments['mypdf.pdf'] = File.read('#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/test.pdf')
mail(:to => guru****@gmail.com, :from => guru****@gmail.com, :subject => 'Attachment Test Mail', :body => 'Regards, Guru')
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I have a same issue for 'Noname' and corrupted.

I am using below code:

```
attachments['126539_statistics.pdf'] = File.read("app/assets/pdfs/126539_statistics.pdf")
mail(:to => email, :subject => subject, :body => message)
```

No any issue for send mail with attachment...